# "Property 'action' does not exist on type..." error in createReducer() NgRx function

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-reducers

I'm refactoring my NgRx reducer to use the `createReducer()` function instead of the traditional switch statement, but I'm getting the following errors:

```
ERROR in src/app/store/price.reducer.ts(17,32): error TS2339: Property 'action' does not exist on type 'IUser & TypedAction<"[Websocket Service] Get User"> & { type: "[Websocket Service] Get User"; }'.
    src/app/store/price.reducer.ts(18,34): error TS2339: Property 'action' does not exist on type 'IPrice & TypedAction<"[Websocket Service] New Prices"> & { type: "[Websocket Service] New Prices"; }'.
```

This is my `createReducer()` function and the exported reducer itself:

```
const userPriceReducer = createReducer(
  defaultState,
  on(actions.getUser, (state, {action}) => ({ ...state, user: { firstName: <string>action.firstName, lastName: <string>action.lastName, age: <number>action.age } })),
  on(actions.newPrices, (state, {action}) => ({ ...state, prices: { ...state.prices, ...{[action.product_id]: <number>action.price } } }))
)

export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return userPriceReducer(state, action);
}
```

And here are my actions:

```
export const NEW_PRICES = '[Websocket Service] New Prices';
export const GET_USER = '[Websocket Service] Get User';

export const newPrices = createAction(
  NEW_PRICES,
  props<IPrice>()
);

export const getUser = createAction(
  GET_USER,
  props<IUser>()
);
```

`IPrice` and `IUser` are interfaces that describe the shape of the action data.

The documentation that I've read about this says that the second argument inside the curly braces after `state` in the `createReducer()` function (where I've put `{action}`) is supposed to be the payload of the action, however since I'm using `createAction()` for my actions, there is no actual `payload` property in the action as there used to be and the action itself carries the data. I have no problem accessing and saving this data when using the switch statement approach. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your action doesn't have an action property, it should be

```
const userPriceReducer = createReducer(
  defaultState,
  on(actions.getUser, (state, action) => ({ ...state, user: { firstName: <string>action.firstName, lastName: <string>action.lastName, age: <number>action.age } })),
  on(actions.newPrices, (state, action) => ({ ...state, prices: { ...state.prices, ...{[action.product_id]: <number>action.price } } }))
)
```

or:

```
const userPriceReducer = createReducer(
  defaultState,
  on(actions.getUser, (state, {firstName,lastName,age}) => ({ ...state, user: { firstName: <string>firstName, lastName: <string>lastName, age: <number>age } })),
  on(actions.newPrices, (state, {price}) => ({ ...state, prices: { ...state.prices, ...{[action.product_id]: <number>price } } }))
)
```

Comment: Wow, it was as simple as removing the curly braces. Now I feel silly. Thank you very much for the quick response.